# Add a chapter and the bibliography to the maintoc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

For a research paper I need to add an appendix which needs to have its own table of contents.

To keep up with the guidelines, I also need to have the bibliography and the declaration located after the appendix. Both shall only appear in the maintoc.

Also on a different site I found the following approach, which looked promising to me, but being quite new to LaTeX, I could not find a solution to my problem.

Is there any possibility to add the bibliography and the declaration to the maintoc?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\maintoc}{
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{
      \value{tocdepth}=-10000
    }
    \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixtoc}{
  \begingroup
    \edef\@alltocdepth{\the\value{tocdepth}}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{-10000}
    \renewcommand*{\appendixattoc}{
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}
    }
    \tableofcontents
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{\@alltocdepth}
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\appendixattoc}{
}
\g@addto@macro\appendix{
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixattoc}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maintoc
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}

\appendix
\appendixtoc
\chapter{Annex I}
\section{Section of Annex I}
\chapter{Annex II}

\printbibliography
\addchap{Declaration of academic honesty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` for the one part.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (based on https://komascript.de/node/2115)

Here is a suggestion without any additional package:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
%%%
\DeclareNewTOC[
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={\contentsname~(\appendixname)}
]{atoc}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{appendixwithtoc}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \appendix
  \addchaptertocentry{}{\appendixname}
  \listofatocs
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{\hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}}%
}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{\hypersetup{bookmarkstype=toc}}%
}
\makeatother
%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}
\cite{baez/article}

\begin{appendixwithtoc}
\chapter{Annex I}
\section{Section of Annex I}
\chapter{Annex II}
\end{appendixwithtoc}

\printbibliography
\addchap{Declaration of academic honesty}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as in the original answer.

Note: If you get an error message regarding undefined command `\ext@toc`, then update your KOMA-Script version or add the following code to your preamble:

```
\ifundefinedorrelax{ext@toc}{%
  \newcommand*{\ext@toc}{toc}
  \renewcommand{\addtocentrydefault}[3]{%
    \expandafter\tocbasic@addxcontentsline\expandafter{\ext@toc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }
}{}
```

---

**Original answer**

Here is a suggestion using [`scrwfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrwfile) that works only with KOMA-Script classes:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\TOCclone[\contentsname~(\appendixname)]{toc}{atoc}
\newcommand\StartAppendixEntries{}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{%
  \renewcommand\StartAppendixEntries{\value{tocdepth}=-10000\relax}%
}
\AfterTOCHead[atoc]{%
  \edef\maintocdepth{\the\value{tocdepth}}%
  \value{tocdepth}=-10000\relax%
  \renewcommand\StartAppendixEntries{\value{tocdepth}=\maintocdepth\relax}%
}
\newenvironment{appendixwithtoc}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \appendix
  \addchaptertocentry{}{\appendixname}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begingroup}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\StartAppendixEntries}
  \listofatoc
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}
}
%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I}
\chapter{Chapter II}
\cite{baez/article}

\begin{appendixwithtoc}
\chapter{Annex I}
\section{Section of Annex I}
\chapter{Annex II}
\end{appendixwithtoc}

\printbibliography
\addchap{Declaration of academic honesty}
\end{document}
```

Note that `scrwfile` is still an alpha version but it is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

[image]

[image]